# Python method URL argument

Tags: python, pip

I am writing a feed scraping program with Python and there is a syntax error when I run the program on the console.
I am using python 3.8 and I installed requests and bs4 using the pip install command.
the error:

```
  File "scraping.py", line 4
    def hackernews("https://news.ycombinator.com/rss"):
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def hackernews_rss('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss'):
    try:
        r = requests.get()
        return print('The scraping job succeeded: ', r.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ')
        print(e)
print('Starting scraping')
hackernews_rss()
print('Finished scraping')
```

the expected output should be:

```
starting scrapping 
2000
finished scraping
```

Comment: Python is telling you exactly what the problem is.  `def hackernews_rss('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss'):` is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: you can only set a constant to a variable in a function definition.

Comment: If you Google for "python defining functions", you'll get lots of options that will teach you about Python functions.  The first one seems like a good one:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this, set the url as a variable

```
link = "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss"
```

then call it as an argument inside the function

```
def hackernews(link):
    req = requests.get(link)
```

And then make sure to call the link again when printing at the bottom of your code:

```
print("started scraping")
hackernews(link)
print("finished scraping")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* takes an identifier, which the *call* provides a value for. The identifier provides the name you will use to refer to the called-with value inside the body of the function.

```
def hackernews_rss(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        return print('The scraping job succeeded: ', r.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ')
        print(e)

print('Starting scraping')
hackernews_rss('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss')
print('Finished scraping')
```

If you want to hard-code the URL to use, you can do so with a default parameter value (which allows you to specify a URL at call time *or* call without an argument to use the default):

```
def hackernews_rss(url='https://news.ycombinator.com/rss'):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        return print('The scraping job succeeded: ', r.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ')
        print(e)

print('Starting scraping')
# The following is equivalent to hackernews_rss('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss')
hackernews_rss()
print('Finished scraping')
```

or more directly (and without the option to override it)

```
def hackernews_rss():
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss')
        return print('The scraping job succeeded: ', r.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ')
        print(e)

print('Starting scraping')
# The following is equivalent to hackernews_rss('https://news.ycombinator.com/rss')
hackernews_rss()
print('Finished scraping')
```

In all three cases, you need to pass a URL to `requests.get()`, which *cannot* be called without an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Way to define python function is

```
def function_name(args):
    function_code
    return function_result
// while calling function
result = function_name("some args")
```

In your code you are proving arguments in definition. Which is invalid syntax.
Please follow the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to learn more!